# How to print multiple variables values using loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables

I have multiple array variable in my page and i need to add them to google charts and make between 15 to 20 charts but for more easier i want to use a loop to print them
All the variables have something in common in there names
how to use one loop to print all variable

example: I have this variable :

```
$productshirts = ['red','green'];
$productpants = ['bleu','yellow'];
$productdress = ['green','gold'];
$products = ['shirts','pants','dress'];
```

now i need to  print them in on code using loop foreach

```
foreach ($products as $product){
print_r('product'.$product);
}
```

but it not work. I get "productshurts , productpants , productdress" and not the array

so how to make them return the data in the array????

Thanks

Comment: Play around a little with loops and the arrays you have got. You will certainly be able to figure that out yourself. Invest a little patience and you will actually _learn_ how to use the language.

Comment: @arkascha i already spend a half day with no progressing that's why I'm asking

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really believe that, actually. Please show us a few of your attempts, a few of your tries. Thanks.

Comment: i used this print_r(${'product'}.$product) and other but it turn around the problem not fix it . i only need hoe to add $ to the variable to see it but i dont know how??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is calling "Variable variables" http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php here is your solution. Just change print loop to this code.

```
foreach ($products as $product){
    $var = 'product'.$product;
    print_r($$var);
}
```

It outputs

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => green ) Array ( [0] => bleu [1] => yellow ) Array ( [0] => green [1] => gold )
```

Comment: Thank you @tanaydin i see that while I'm searching the net but i didn't understand it . Now it much clear..

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($products as $product){
    print_r(${'product'.$product});
}
```

it will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => green
)
Array
(
    [0] => bleu
    [1] => yellow
)
Array
(
    [0] => green
    [1] => gold
)
```

On a note (and I don't know if you can change the stracture) it would be more readable (and easier to use and scale) to use a multi dimentional array

```
$product['shirts'] = ['red','green'];
$product['pants'] = ['bleu','yellow'];
```

etc

Comment: thanks for your help but for the code it just a example not the real code cause the real code is google analytics and it sooo much complicated that why i put it like that